# Gnuradio: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dpd'

Tags: python, gnuradio

I successfully built gnuradio 3.8.1.0 (Python 3.8.10) from source on Ubuntu 20 focal (did not apt install).  I executed the entire tutorial and ran each one without issue.  Gnuradio worked perfectly.

Then I successfully built and installed gr-dpd according to directions.
(https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-dpd).  I was able to build the flowgraph for DPD successfully. (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnuradio/gr-dpd/master/raw/RLS_test_run_two_tone_setup.jpg) However, when I ran it I got the following:

```
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.8.1.0 >>>

Block paths:
    /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
    /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks

Loading: "/home/user0/gnuradio/DPD/RLS_test_run_two_tone_setup.grc"
>>> Done

Generating: '/home/user0/gnuradio/DPD/MyDPD.py'

Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/user0/gnuradio/DPD/MyDPD.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user0/gnuradio/DPD/MyDPD.py", line 36, in <module>
    import dpd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dpd'

>>> Done (return code 1)
```

What should I do?  (I am new to Python.)

Comment: have you tried `pip install dpd` ?

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you for the reply.  There is a dpd package but https://pypi.org/project/DPD/ is an unrelated package and installing it did not fix the  problem.

Comment: SOLVED.  For some reason, probably my fault, gnurado python packages for gnuradio and dpd were installed in /usr/local/python3 and /usr/local/python3.8 dist_packages dir.  I just moved the dpd package next to gnuradio's package.  HTH next fellow.